# Canvas.drawRect works only once in a for-each loop

Tags: java, android, canvas, foreach, drawrect

I am trying to create a custom keyboard for my device, and I would like to draw my own custom background for each key in the keyboard. For some reason the canvas will only draw the first key's background, and ignores the rest.
Here's the source for my onDraw function:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paintBack = new Paint();
    paintBack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paintBack.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for(Key key: keys) {
        Rect fillRect = new Rect();
        fillRect.left = key.x + keyMargin;
        fillRect.right = key.width - keyMargin;
        fillRect.top = key.y + keyMargin;
        fillRect.bottom = key.height - keyMargin;

        System.out.println("X: " + Integer.toString(key.x) + ", Y: " + Integer.toString(key.y) + ", W: " + Integer.toString(key.width) + ", H: " + Integer.toString(key.height));
        canvas.drawRect(fillRect, paintBack);
    }
}
```

And here's the output I'm receiving from the `System.out.println` call I make for each key:

```
X: 0, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 79, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 158, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 237, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 316, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 395, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 474, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 553, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 632, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 711, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 790, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 869, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 948, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 1027, Y: 0, W: 158, H: 80  
X: 0, Y: 80, W: 119, H: 80  
X: 119, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 198, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 277, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 356, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 435, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 514, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 593, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 672, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 751, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 830, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 909, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 988, Y: 80, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 1067, Y: 80, W: 119, H: 80  
X: 0, Y: 160, W: 139, H: 80  
X: 139, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 218, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 297, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 376, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 455, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 534, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 613, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 692, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 771, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 850, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 929, Y: 160, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 1008, Y: 160, W: 178, H: 80  
X: 0, Y: 240, W: 178, H: 80  
X: 178, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 257, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 336, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 415, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 494, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 573, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 652, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 731, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 810, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 889, Y: 240, W: 79, H: 80  
X: 968, Y: 240, W: 218, H: 80  
X: 0, Y: 320, W: 119, H: 80  
X: 119, Y: 320, W: 99, H: 80  
X: 218, Y: 320, W: 717, H: 80  
X: 935, Y: 320, W: 99, H: 80  
X: 1034, Y: 320, W: 158, H: 80
```

The output clearly shows all coordinates and sizes for all keys, but for some reason the `canvas.drawRect` method will only fire once.

Is there something I am overlooking here, or am I just approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: should be `fillRect.right = key.x + key.width - keyMargin`, similar change to bottom part

Comment: @pskink thank you, that fixed it

Comment: (translated) graag gedaan ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @pskink's comment I changed my code to look like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paintBack = new Paint();
    paintBack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paintBack.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for(Key key: keys) {
        Rect fillRect = new Rect();
        fillRect.left = key.x + keyMargin;
        fillRect.right = key.x + key.width - keyMargin;
        fillRect.top = key.y + keyMargin;
        fillRect.bottom = key.y + key.height - keyMargin;

        System.out.println("X: " + Integer.toString(key.x) + ", Y: " + Integer.toString(key.y) + ", W: " + Integer.toString(key.width) + ", H: " + Integer.toString(key.height));
        canvas.drawRect(fillRect, paintBack);
    }
}
```

(Note that I changed `fillRect.right` to `key.x + key.width - keyMargin` and `fillRect.bottom` to `key.y + key.height - keyMargin`)
That worked for me.

Comment: You should consider not creating a new paint object in onDraw and having paint object a instance variable you just call.

Comment: i have a private variable in my class, i put it in the function just for demo purposes so that the code would at least run if tested.